# multiple internal redirects to different indexes in folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, internal

I'm new to htaccess and I'm searching for a way to get an internal redirect to set 2 URLs to different folders.

`example.com/cms/`
and everything behind the /cms/ needs to go to
`rootfolder` -> `cms`

`example.com/`(the rest of the pages)
needs to go to
`rootfolder` -> `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try addng this to your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Essentially:

- If the request is for `/cms`, let it get resolved to `/cms` directly
- If the request is already for `/public`, let it get resolved directly
- If the request is for an existing file or directory, let it resolve
- Otherwise, rewrite the request appending a `/public` in front of the URI

Comment: Thnks for the clear example :) I cant test i right now but will try tonight. Thnks again.

Comment: I just found out that it the redirect to the public folder gives me an 403 error ? i know that its an forbidden error but do you have any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: @Controvi Do you have directory index turned off or are missing an `index.html` or `index.php` file in /public/?

Comment: No a have an index.php inside both folders. But i noticed something.
when i navigate to the /public it gives no error but when i go to the root url then it gives a 403 error.

Comment: @Controvi not sure why that's happening, try adding this rule right after the `RewriteEngine On`: `RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.php [L]`

Comment: It worked perfectly :) it was just a coincidence that i found it because XD but thanks again for the help